# decryption + base64 issues in python using AWS

Tags: python, encryption, base64

I have client_info table in a PostgreSQL database in which there is 1 field (address) I want to store the encrypted value. But when I want to send the field as an API result, I want to decrypt it and send the decrypted address.

Below are my encrypted and decrypted functions (I am also doing base64 encoding/decoding along with encryption/decryption respectively)

```
PADDING = lambda s: s + (32 - len(s) % 32) * ' '

    def encrypt_info(str):
        try:
            encrypted_info = b64encode(obj.encrypt(settings.PADDING(str)))
            return encrypted_info
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error in encryption: %s", e.message)
            return str


    def decrypt_info(str):
        try:
            decrypted_info = obj.decrypt(b64decode(str)).rstrip()
            return decrypted_info
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error in decryption: %s", e.message)
            return str
```

where obj is the object of AES using a key. (Cannot share it for security reasons).

The encryption is working fine as of now and whenever a new row is inserted, the address field is encrypted and stored in the database.

The problem I am facing is:

1. For the addresses which are encrypted, decrypt_info is giving me the
   correct results.
2. For addresses which are not encrypted (the
       older addresses which are already in database), the exception is thrown in some cases, but in some
       cases, decrypt_info() is not throwing any exception and I am getting
       some junk like �ƭ�H�e̪Cs8Lqڎ����~Sp��.���

I want the function to be working in all the cases. Can you please help me in this ?
I found some functions to check whether the string is base64 encoded or not and then perform the operation, but that is not working in all the cases.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reliable way to tell if string is "raw" or result of AES encryption.

If you want to keep backward compatibility, you need to write some flag to DB along with messages to distinguish new/old data.